# Juju bootstrap to CloudVPS OpenStack machine has 3 ip's

Tags: juju, openstack

When bootstrapping to the new CloudVPS beta OpenStack cloud, the bootstrap instance is getting three separate IP's allocated to it.

Is this normal for Juju to do or require when bootstrapping to OpenStack type or is this something on CloudVPS side?

Tried Juju 1.7.0 and after that downgraded to 1.6.5 - happens with both.

[image: pic]

Comment: Any updates on this issue? Have you tried with 1.18 by any chance?

Comment: This ended up being an issue with the CloudVPS Compute beta - using the Nova CLI tools produced the same result, but from cust support got a specific network interface to use which fixed the issue with cli tools. They will fix the issue in the public launch - Juju should work then too without this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being an issue with the CloudVPS Compute beta - using the Nova CLI tools produced the same result, but from cust support got a specific network interface to use which fixed the issue with cli tools. They will fix the issue in the public launch - Juju should work then too without this issue.